# Reference request: linear operators into $L^\infty$ can be extended presrving the norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a normed linear space and $Y\subset X$ a linear subspace.

I remember that any linear map $L\colon Y\to L^\infty(\Omega)$ can be extended to a linear map $\tilde{L}\colon X\to L^\infty(\Omega)$ that has the same operator norm. (Under some assumptions, I guess $\sigma$-finiteness, on the measure that on $\Omega$)

Does anyone have a reference for that?

Comment: thanks, that helped. its on p.111 in "Banach spaces for analysts" by Wojtaszczyk.